# How to open a Pickerview(dropdown) on UITextView click in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, drop-down-menu, uitextfield, uipickerview

I'm working on  a project where i want to add a dropdown list for selecting category.
Please check the screenshot(currently its `UITextField` only).
[image]

When user click on `UITextField` how can i show PickerView at bottom of screen

I tried some codes but none of them are working

```
    - (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    pickrView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 400,self.view.frame.size.width,300);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.50];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    pickrView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, pickrView.frame.size.width, pickrView.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:pickrView];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Pickerview is added or not

Comment: [self.view addSubview:pickrView]; to add before animation

Answer (score 4):

You need a pickerview instead of keyboard when clicked on textfield. So for that you have to assign pickerview to 'inputview' property of UITextField while creating textfield.

Let me explain it with an example.

Firstly Creating textfield

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     UITextField *cellTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
     cellTextField.frame = CGRectMake(20, 12, 180, 20);
     cellTextField.inputView = [self createPicker];
}
```

Creating PickerView

```
- (UIView *)createPicker {

    UIView *pickerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 216)];
    pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:109.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:120.0/255.0 alpha:1];

    UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 300, 120)];
    picker.delegate = self;
   [pickerView addSubview:picker];

   return pickerView;
```

}

By doing this you will get pickerview when you tap on textfield.